# Locker Service and 3rd party library, how to pass Security review?

Tags: javascript, locker-service, security-review, libraries

Is it a way to use 3rd party library/framework like `Vue`/`Angular` and bypass security review by **Salesforce**. Because only option to use those kind of library seems possible with version `39.0` which is automatically fail.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

We always try to improve the compatibility of Locker with third party frameworks. Maybe there is solution for the specific problem you are facing?

Alternatively you can use a Lightning Container Component:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/container_overview.htm

A good overview of the pros and cons of each one is here:

https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2017/02/lockerservice-lightning-container-third-party-libraries-lightning-components.html

Answer (score -1):

Please do not use Vue or Angular in your Lightning components. It is not idiomatic, things will break, and everything will be super slow.

Use Lightning Web Components. They are as powerful as Vue or React, idiomatic, supported by the VSCode IDE, and compliant with web standards.

Comment: it's such a nonsense...
If you will try to work with React or Vue and you have an open mind, you will never want to work with LWC again, it's another level of development

Comment: The issue is not whether or not to use Angular within LIghtning components; it is how to make tens of thousands of lines of legacy, existing Angular code work within Lightning components, without spending person-years rewriting it, or leaving it in the Visualforce ghetto.

Comment: @kamezaburo i don't believe such code should run inside of lightning component. It will violate the UX guidelines of Salesforce, and be generally speaking horrible for the end-user. Maybe start small and rewrite only the key features of the Angular app while exposing your app somewhere on Heroku in the meantime.

Comment: It is easy enough to say "AngularJS should not run inside of Lightning components", but as I'm sure you can see there is no easy way to run a legacy AngularJS app built to run under Visualforce, with all that implies in terms of use of sforce, or taking data from Apex controllers referenced by Apex page files, in a separate environment such as Heroku.